# Could be possible that $\langle\gamma' , \gamma''\rangle$ is constant but $\|\gamma'(t)\|$ is not constant?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma: (a,b)\to \mathbb R^3$ be a differentiable curve. Note that if $\|\gamma'(t)\|=k\ne 0$ where $k$ is a constant, then $\|\gamma'(t)\|^2=\langle\gamma(t),\gamma(t)\rangle=k^2$. If we derivate both sides of the equality, we can conclude that $\gamma'(t) ,\gamma''(t)$ are perpendicular,   i.e. $\langle\gamma',\gamma''\rangle=0$. In particular it's constant. I want to know something more general.

> **My question:** Given $\gamma: (a,b)\to \mathbb R^3$ a differentiable curve, does there exist a reparametrization $
> \widetilde\gamma:(c,d)\to \mathbb R^3 
> $ such that the vectors $
> \widetilde\gamma'$ and $ 
> \widetilde\gamma'' 
> $ have constant angle, i.e $
> \langle\widetilde\gamma'$ , $ 
> \widetilde\gamma''\rangle=c
> $, but the norm of the vector $
> \widetilde\gamma'$ is not constant?

Comment: I think maybe you need the regularity condition?

Comment: Be careful. Unless you know $\|\tilde\gamma{}'\|$ and $\|\tilde\gamma{}''\|$ are also constant, this dot product condition does *not* say constant angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume the regularity condition, otherwise this is impossible. Now let $\gamma$ be a curve parameterised by arc-length $s$. So $\|\gamma'\|=1$. We now re-parameterise $\gamma$ by $s^{\frac{3}{2}}$. Then set $\beta=\gamma\circ t $, where $t(s)^=s^{\frac{3}{2}}$. Thus $\|\beta'\|=\frac{3\sqrt s}{2}$, and $\beta''=\gamma'' (t')^2+\gamma' t''$. Therefore $\langle \beta',\beta''\rangle=\langle \frac{3\sqrt s}{2}\gamma',\frac{3}{4\sqrt s}\gamma'\rangle=\frac{9}{8}$. So you could always do it, when the curve is reguler.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: Thanks for the example awlllower, but my question it's about a general curve (maybe the only hypothesis could be sufficiently differentiable but nothing else). If it's true that I can find such reparametrization

Comment: @Eustass How about the revised version?

Comment: Thanks dude! This is a very good answer :D!

Comment: Glad that I can help. :D

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following curve.
F(t)=(t^(3/2),0,0) where t>=0.